# Box zoom out in leaflet maps

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using leaflet for creating maps in web and geoserver for serving maps as WMS layer.Leaflet has box zoom-in tool when we click shift and drag on the map.

[image: leaflet box zoom]
Similarly I need box zoom-out in leaflet like in QGIS

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this using leaflet?

Comment: Not out of box. I had some success with hooking into `boxzoomstart` and `boxzoomend` but it gets messy and is a bit clunky. I would recommend copying the relevant code from leaflet.js to create a custom `boxzoominout` plugin that takes a `direction` option, and then disable the default `boxzoom` option like this `L.map('map', { ..., boxzoom: false, boxzoominout: true, boxzoomdirection: 'out', ... }` and then you could use the button click handler to change the `boxzoomdirection` from `'in'` to `'out'`, or whatever. Might try to write one myself later, but gotta run.

Comment: but How to get the code of zoom out from leaflet.js. There is no code for box zoom. So is there any way to write the own code for box zoom out